# simple example of gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to write gnuplot command for a file which just I have one column of that. In the file and that column is Y, But in the file I don't have X's column.X's column element are

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

.Pay attention to the belowe think they are my in file witch they 
"

```
12
43
65
76
12
56
```

"
As you see I have Y's element but I do not have X's element in my file,I mean X elemat is based on the row number.I guess there should be an command in gnuplot which does this.

Comment: I think this is either a bot trying to get reputation or a reputation scam. Not sure, but feel free to check: http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175518366/gnuplot-make-a-chart-with-one-column-witch-in-not-exict and http://w3facility.org/question/gnuplot-make-a-chart-with-one-column-witch-in-not-exict/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for single column files.  The difference is that the standard numbering is to number x=0,1,2,...

Here's my data (in file temp.dat)

```
12 
43 
65 
76 
12 
56
```

Plot with

```
    gnuplot> plot "temp.dat" with linespoints title "Single column data"
```

or similar.

To shift the x-axis so that x=1,2,3...

```
    gnuplot> plot "temp.dat" using ($0+1):1 with linespoints title "Single column data"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by cat'ing the file and then plotting: `cat temp.dat | gnuplot -p -e "plot '<cat' with linespoints"`